# "pyinstall" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Saludos comunidad pythoniana, quiero compliar un archivo .py a un .exe pero para ello necesito de pyinstaller. Llevo mucho tiempo intentandolo instalar con python 2.7 3.8 y 3.9 y no me deja. Siempre me sale el mismo error:

"pyinstall" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Ya no se que  hacer alguien me puede ayudar porfavor

Comment: Probaste instalarlo usando el nombre "pyinstaller"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyinstaller es una librería adicional que no viene en la instalación por defecto del lenguaje debes hacerla mediante pip que es el manager de librerías de python

usa desde la consola

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

e instalara lo necesario para funcionar

Answer (score 0):

use esto:

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile -w Miarchivo.py
```

y genero el Exec